# How can I put price on my nft with my token

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I want to create an NFT Game in which users can buy NFT with my custom token.

for example, Decentraland has a token called Mana.
as you can see they listed the NFT with Mana!

### [Decentraland NFT example on OpenSea](https://opensea.io/assets/0xf87e31492faf9a91b02ee0deaad50d51d56d5d4d/115792089237316195423570985008687907827068242412728302352777739235666977357795)

[image]

In OpenSea there is an option to list NFT with a custom token but it's deprecated

[image]

as you can see there is a custom token like GALA

[image]

but it's deprecated and I can't add the new token

[image]

## What is my problem

I know how to create a token and NFT
but I don't know how to list it on my custom token

## What I tried

I could create a token and NFT

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract Shiaf is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("Shiaf", "MTK") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 10000000 * 10 ** decimals());
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't upload Image because I'm new!

Answer (score -1):

Well, this depends in what you prefer to do, but you could do your own marketplace to sell the nfts and only accept as a payment method your own token or you could write some mint function for your nft that in order for mint take some amount of tokens from the user

Comment: this is exactly what I want but I don't know how to accept as a payment method my own token

Comment: I watched a tutorial about how to create a marketplace but I don't know how to change the payment system:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZWCzsB1xUE

Comment: first check how to interact with other contracts inside one smart contract, then you deploy your token contract and then the nft contract, then inside the contract that will receive the tokens you call the transferFrom function of the tokens check if it has failed or not if not send to the user the nft, as a note to make that work the user should first call approve function of the token and approve the contract that will receive the tokens, for more information check openzeppelin docs